# Arrange dual monitors up and down instead of side by side

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

Normally when we arrange and extended display we can set it either to the left or right and on moving the mouse to that particular direction, the cursor moves to the next screen. But suppose I have set an extended display (in my case a TV) above my laptop monitor, will it be possible to arrange the screens vertically. That means on moving the mouse up the cursor should go into the second display. Is it possible to do this in Windows 10 or even in any Linux OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Start**  > **Settings**  > **System** > **Display** and under **Rearrange your displays** you can drag the monitors arround to correspond with their real world placement.

[image]